# ipython scrambled terminal, after resizing window

Tags: python, terminal, ipython, readline

I run ipython(2) in a terminal (debian stable). After resizing the window with the mouse, the printouts of ipython are annoyingly meesed up, eg:

- if one input line is too long, instead of starting a new line, the first line is overwritten
- calling a command help (eg by `plot?`), the page is broken, part is missing when scrolling it

Something probably related is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205386/resizing-the-terminal-window-for-ipython-command-prompt), and discussed [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8469).

I tried without success: installing (by `pip`) `readline` and/or `gnureadline`; the `!clear` command in ipython; many terminal emulators (the qt ipython console doesn't have this problem), and `tmux`.

Do you know a possible solution / workaround to have ipython in a clean re-sizable terminal window?

EDIT: the problem is not there in ipython3 (3.5.3)

Comment: Same problem on OSX for me. Surprisingly, nothing is out there that seems to address this.

Comment: not 100% sure, but today I think got this even without resizing the window

Comment: I used to have the same problem, at some point the problem disappeared... Couldn't you possibly find a backport of a newer IPython release?

Comment: @gboffi I moved to Debian stretch, got ipython 2.7.13, and the issue is still there.

Comment: Ooops, I switched from Debian's IPython to Anaconda's one, that is the point at which the problem disappeared...  sorry for the noise I'd possibly added.